# How to install pepper flash

Tags: flash, chromium

I cant install pepper flash on lubuntu 15.10

I want to get it running on chromium 32 bit system.

Answer (score 1):

1. enable the "Canonicle partner" in "software & updates"
   [image: software & updates]
2. refresh & install adobe-flashplugin
   [image: adobe-flashplugin]

---

I found this on the internet:

sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash

Comment: I tried that but it only shows the old 11.2 flash player

Comment: There will be no future 32-bit builds of Flash from Google, as they've stopped building Chrome on 32-bit.

Comment: Maybe try this: sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash

Comment: @JulianLai I did it and it installed but still it didn't work no flash player in chromium

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work for 32 bit version? It works on my 64 bit version very well.

Comment: I think that is the issue here, love google i think they might be worse then microsoft